# Amen between Hashkiveinu and Yir'u Eineinu in maariv

Tags: tefilla, nuschaot, tractate-brachot, amen, italy

Based on [Brachot 45b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.45b.22?lang=bi) and [Yerushalmi Brachot 5:4/40b](https://mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r1105.htm), many communities have the custom of saying *amen* after several of their own *brachot*. One of the places where some add *amen* is at the end of the *brachot* after *shema*. In the evening, the series of *brachot* after *shema* consist of *emet v'emuna* אמת ואמונה (ending in *ga'al yisrael* גאל ישראל), *hashkiveinu* השכיבנו, and *yir'u eineinu* יראו עיננו (although some omit the latter, and some combine the last two into one *bracha*).

From what I understand, the *amen* must come at the end of the series of *brachot* (see Mishneh Torah Tefillah 1:16–18, Rashi, Rosh, Rabbeinu Yonah, etc on the gemara). Thus, one would expect this *amen* to come at the end of *yir'u eineinu*. However, in Minhag Roma as practiced now in Israel (see [here](https://524f1f52-e6e8-4762-a04d-3474189e42c4.filesusr.com/ugd/8cabfe_c6f24da374d445379b9cf2aeb4cd9327.pdf), p 110 of the PDF, p 96 on the page), the *amen* comes at the end of *hashkiveinu*! Perhaps the intention is to separate between the Talmudic *brachot* (*ga'al yisrael* and *hashkiveinu*) and the Geonic *bracha* of *yir'u eineinu*, just like *amen* after *boneh yerushalayim* separates the Biblical *brachot* from the Rabbinic *bracha* in *birkat hamazon*?

I'm interested in literature on this point, and whether my guess is correct. In particular, I'm interested in discussions of whether to place *amen* after *hashkiveinu* or after *yir'u eineinu*, in contexts where both *brachot* are said independently (so, not where the latter is omitted or where it's combined with *hashkiveinu*, and not where *amen* is omitted entirely).

Comment: I'm just saying that it's slightly different in each city. Piattelli's (fantastic) book is not even followed in Rome. For example, in Milan (IIRC) they said it silently only on _motzaei shabbat_ by standing up. I couldn't ever figure out that custom.

Comment: @Kazibácsi Do you know what they *do* follow in Rome and Milan?

Comment: Piattelli moved to Jerusalem, and since he's quite a scholar of the Italian nusach, they do many things that they do not even say in Rome. In Milan they use [this book](http://www.morasha.it/sbr/index.html) which mainly corresponds to the one edited by [R' Dario Disegni](https://www.nli.org.il/en/books/NNL_ALEPH002204815/NLI) (still used).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the position of R' Yosef Karo (OC 236:4). See plenty of literature surrounding his writings there.

Comment: Thanks! He's more expansive in Beit Yosef. By "plenty of literature" do you mean just the Gra, or am I missing commentaries "on the page"?

Comment: @magic truthfully I didn't even check all the possible sources there just now, but assumed most of what you seek if it exists should be referenced by or through there. (Along the lines of your suggestion, the most important source in my opinion is actually referenced obliquely earlier in BY OC 51, but it's somewhat speculative to apply it here.)

Comment: Yeah, based on OC 51 and other Rishonic discussions, I could guess what was going on here, but wanted something more explicit. Thanks.