Should one say Amen to הַמֶּֽלֶךְ בִּכְבוֹדוֹ תָּמִיד יִמְלוֹךְ עָלֵֽינוּ if it is not one's minhag to say it?
There is a beracha that many Ashkenazim (especially in Chutz Laaretz) say as the final beracha of Birchot Keriyat Shema of Maariv (before the Amidah) while many Sefardim do not say it.
Should a (e.g.) Sefardi say Amen to this beracha i.e. הַמֶּֽלֶךְ בִּכְבוֹדוֹ תָּמִיד יִמְלוֹךְ עָלֵֽינוּ, when in a shul where they says it, when he hears it from the Chazan?
For example, in Yalkut Yosef Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 25:54, and OC 422:4, he writes that Sefardim shouldn't answer amen to Ashkenazi Birchat Hallel when it is half-Hallel, and shouldn't answer amen to Ashkenazim making a beracha on their Tefillin Shel Rosh (because many Sefardim do not say these berachot themselves).
The principles behind not saying amen to a beracha you do not say yourself - do they apply here?

Note this bracha was originally widespread among all Jewish communities and it's not specifically an ashkenazi/sefardi/geography thing. Some people from all places still say it

Duplicate? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78186/answering-amen-to-baruch-hashem-lolam-in-maariv

The berachah of יראו עינינו is actually part of the old Nusach Bavel (see Seder R' 'Amram Gaon and Siddur R' Sa'adya Gaon). It is currently said in the following nuschaot (and potentially others): Ashkenaz, Maroc, Polen, and many versions of Sfard (except motza"sh and motzay"t). I've never seen an Italian Nusach Italia siddur, so I don't know if they say it

We have an Israeli in our minyan who responds אמן and when he leads, says it, since it's the nusach of the sha"tz's siddur.

According to the both the gra and admit hazaken one should not say this bracha at all as it is a hefsek between geula and tefila. If you would follow their shita on not saying this bracha it would follow not to say amen to it as well

@NoachMiFrankfurt Italians do say ברוך ה' לעולם, but only on Saturday night. Though I don't have a siddur at hand to check the concluding blessing.

@Dude That doesn't follow.  If someone decides to randomly say mezonos and eat a cookie there, everyone agrees that that's a hefsek and he shouldn't have done it, but it's still a valid mezonos and you'd say amen.

Yes it follows that you should not say amen to a bracha you should not say.

@Dude Is that true?  If it's a bracha levatala or she'einah tzricha, sure.  But this is a valid bracha that is (accd to these shitos) better not to say for an external reason.

@Heshy what makes it valid? There's supposed to be no hefsek between geula and tefila and it was not introduced by chazal. Why can someone after the fact make a bracha to be added then?

@Dude if you break between Geula and Tefilla you lost that connection and move on in life. You aren't forever forbidden from speaking.

@Dude If someone said mezonos and ate between geulah and tefillah, would you say amen?

@Heshy I would think not. I'm not allowed to stop between geula and tefilla, and answering amen on an unrelated b'racha is stopping (unlike answering amen on hashkiveinu/ ga'al yisrael, which is a related bracha (and even so answering amen is debated iirc))

Is there a reason to think that the principle of not answering amen on a bracha that is not one's minhag doesn't apply here?

@Loani well, for one, some Sefardim do say it, and those who don't, used to (according to DoubleAA, who generally knows this stuff). Also, I am not 100% clear on how this principle of not saying an amen to a beracha "one doesn't say" works. I would like to learn about that along the way

I was always wondering this as well so thanks for bringing it up :)
It seems to be a machloket haposkim:
Per the comments we need to split the answer into two parts:
Opinions if any brachot are a hefsek at that point (someone davening with the tzibur and hears יראו עינינו) :

In Sefer Ben Ish Chai פרשת פיקודי אות ה פרשה ראשונה he says to not answer amen beacause דאין אומרים אמן דברכות כאן. He is worried about a hefsek at that part.
In Yechaveh Daat 2:30, Rav Ovadia says there is no hefsek to answer amen to brachot at that point.
In the Kaf Hachaim O.C Siman 236 Seif Katan 21 he says,


דוקא בדיבור אסור להפסיק ביניהם אבל לענות קדיש וקדושה וברכו ואמן פשיטא דשרי דלא עדיף מק"ש וברכותיה.

"Specifically speaking one is not allowed to speak between the pesukim of יראו עינינו, but to answer kadish, kedusha, barchu, amen, it would for sure be allowed because it is no better than Shema and its brachot." Although he is talking about speaking in between the pesukim of יראו עינינו we can say the same thing after the pesukim of יראו עינינו that one can answer amen

Mishneh Berurah O.C 236 Seif Katan 5 quoting the Tur says, ומ"מ אין להפסיק בדברים אחרים, meaning that things besides for יראו עינינו, would be a hefsek, but for  יראו עינינו itself one can answer amen.

If there is a problem of answering amen to the actual bracha (someone just walking by and hears this brcha:

In sefer מראה הבזק חלק ג שאלה טז in name of Rav Shaul Israeli he says:


וגם בן ארץ ישראל שנמצא בחו"ל, אף על פי שאינו נוהג לומר יראו עינינו, יענה אמן משום שענין סמיכת גאולה לתפילה ממילא לא נשמר מצד אמירת הקדיש. ומכיון שהללו האומרים את ברכת יראו עינינו שומרים על המנהג שנהגו, ובדין נהגו, כיון שמסיימם בברכה, גם אם אין הוא מתפלל הוא עמהם בעצם התפילה, יענה אמן.

"And also a person from the Land of Israel who is in chutz laretz, even though he does not customarily say יראו עינינו, he should respond Amen because the issue of linking geulah to teffilah is not affected by the recitation of Kaddish. And since those who recite the blessing of יראו עינינו are maintaining a custom that they have observed, and they are correct in doing so because they end with a blessing, even if he is not praying with them, by being with them in the prayer, therefore he should respond Amen."
Now although he was referring to Bnei Chutz laretz and not sefardim I think we can make the connection to sefardim, that if Jews in Eretz Yisrael who don't have a minhag to say יראו עינינו, say amen, then for sefardim as well who don't have the minhag also can answer amen.

לע״ד it seems that according to Shulchan Aruch O.C Siman 236:2, there wouldn't be a problem/issur of saying יראו עינינו, and therefore no problem of answering amen as well.


אין לספר בין גאולה דערבית לתפלה ואף הנוהגין לומר י"ח פסוקים ויראו עינינו אין להפסיק בין יראו עינינו לתפלה ומיהו מה שמכריז ש"צ ר"ח בין קדיש לתפלת ערבית לא הוי הפסק כיון שהוא צורך תפלה וכן יכול לומר ברכו להוציא מי שלא שמע ולא הוי הפסק

"One should not talk between the blessing about redemption (ge'ulah) in the evening and the Amidah; even those who routinely say 18 verses and "yir'u eineinu" should not pause between that paragraph and the Amidah. What about when the reader announces Rosh Chodesh [so people can remember to say ya'aleh ve'yavo] between Kaddish and the evening Amidah? This is not a pause, since it is a requirement for the Amidah; and thus, one could also say that Barchu, to exempt one who did not hear it, wouldn't be considered a hefsek either."
Edit: Recently I have received an answer from Rabbi Yonatan Nacson who said that he has confirmed with Hagoan HaRav Yitzchak Yosef and Hagoan Rav David Yosef that one can answer amen to יראו עינינו. However Rav Ovadia in Moar Yisrael Volume 1 page 7 did not answer amen when he was praying in a minyan that recited this berachah (on one of his trips to South America), since it is not an obligation to answer amen to this berachah, but one may answer if he wants to.

" דאין אומרים אמן דברכות כאן" What does that mean? Many say Amen to שומר עמו ישראל לעד there https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/114219/759

@DoubleAA Maybe he was of the opinion that amen there is an interruption. But anyway, perhaps he would agree to say amen when you're not in the middle of tefilla, so I'm not sure that source fully answers the OP's question.

@magicker what does "when you're not in the middle of tefilla" mean? We're all discussing the same point in davening no? Or is the question just about a random passerby saying amen?

@DoubleAA I meant a random passerby. Obviously that's a side case, but if it makes a difference to the answer, it's surely relevant.

Sorry I took so long. I have updated the question with more clarity on what I think the problem might be, and I think you potentially address my query in the final paragraph. I also want to thank you for the amazing research you did, that I (we) have definitely benefitted from! I'm not sure if I should accept this answer or not, I've drawn attention and a posted a bounty to see if any other answers are forthcoming first. Shkoyach

No problem, I appreciate that Rabbi Kaii

@RabbiKaii, please see my edit in bold
